# How can I create keyboard like buttons with UIInputView?

Tags: ios, keyboard

With iOS 7 Apple introduced `UIInputView`, which allows you to add a custom view above the keyboard that looks like this (you can adjust the height):

[image: UIInputView as the accessory input view]

The [docs state](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIInputView_class/Reference/Reference.html) that:

> The UIInputView class is designed to match the appearance of the standard system keyboard when used as an input view with a responder. When defining your own custom input views or input accessory views, you can use a UIInputView object as the root view and add any subviews you want to create your input view. The input view and its subviews receive tinting and blur effects based on the options you specify at initialization time.

What I do not understand, however, is how I can add additional row of buttons that look like standard keys above the keyboard (such as here in Fantastical):

[image: Fantastical with custom keyboard keys]

Is it possible to a) correctly style system UIButtons so that they appear like keys or b) is there a library that simplifies the rendering of custom keys?

Answer (score 1):

I think this an inputAccessoryView used with the iOS keyboard. Just try by creating a UIView and adding some custom buttons to it and assigning it as the inputAccessoryView.